# Pricing Calculator - Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I stumbled on a very nice pricing matrix on this website.

https://msp.exosource.com/en#!pricing

Does anyone know how it was created? Plugin? Custom? Javascript?

I am looking for something similar, not an exact copy. Thanks!

Comment: It's custom. Keep in mind that asking for plugin or theme recommendations is off topic here, so if you're after an off the shelf solution this isn't the place to ask.

Comment: yep I understand. I was just hoping to identify if it was off the shelf. Obviously is isn't. I will go the custom route then. Thanks.